Ubuntu 23 laptop fails to connect to internet
I tried to connect to a hotspot. Later, the laptop no longer connects to Wifi neither does it pick Ethernet.
Available Wifi networks are shown, but upon clicking on them, the laptop fails to open it.

Ubuntu 23.10 reached EOL in July https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/07/17/ubuntu-23-10-mantic-minotaur-reached-end-of-life-on-july-11-2024/

Ubuntu 23.10 (along with all flavors) is End-of-Life and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/07/17/ubuntu-23-10-mantic-minotaur-reached-end-of-life-on-july-11-2024/   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades
